# How to open another terminal in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to find out how I can create another window from an already-running node.js application that I can output text in from the main application.

Example:
I have a window that displays information (main window), but I want to get another window that displays errors (secondary window) and would close when the main application is stopped. How would I be able to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Update: Nevermind, I found a solution. (answered below)
another update: You could also use express and socket.io to make a logs web page

Comment: What GUI toolkit are you using to generate your windows? (Or are you wanting to affect the terminal emulator that a command-line program is running int?)

Comment: @OmegaGaming32 Please come back and post your answer that you found, as an answer on your question for future users.

Comment: @Brad i ended up just ditching the idea of using a gui, and instead used a package called Terminal-Kit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ditched the idea of an additional GUI and instead used a terminal library called terminal-kit, which worked perfectly for what I wanted to use it for. I’d recommend trying to make an electron app or something similar if you do want to open another GUI.

Comment: That's a good solution. I was just coming here to say "don't open terminal emulator windows, you have no idea what users will have in their config that could conflict with what you're trying to do"